# Tailwind Variants not working with PostCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm using `Tailwind` with `PostCSS` and I'm trying to figure out why the variants are not working but the theme is.

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
theme: {
    extend: {
    ....
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['checked'],
      borderColor: ['checked'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the variants are not working but the theme is"? Please elaborate.

Comment: hi, what i mean is that whatever configuration i put on the `variants` it's not showing up. like how i included the `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` but the effects are not showing up.